# How much of a bond do the market makers typically hold?

Tags: finance, bonds, econophysics

Market makers facilitate a bond issuance by providing somewhere to both buy and sell the bonds of a bond issuance.

I'm trying to understand how the market makers (i.e. the security underwriters such as J.P. Morgan) are affected by devaluation of a bond. Can they become insolvent if the price falls sufficiently, and be affected by chains of default in financial contagion, just like typical creditors who hold bonds?

So, are market makers effectively holders of a bond (and might liquidate their portfolio like a creditor as part of financial contagion, for example, once the price has fallen and they go insolvent)? How much do they typically "hold" of the bond?

Perhaps it starts off as quite small, but can go to zero once the secondary market starts buying and selling?

Comment: “Can they become insolvent”…who- the market maker ? Highly unlikely